# Not able to click on elements of a dropdown list of results using selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am a beginner with the selenium Python library. I want to use it to retrieve informations on tennis players from the following url "https://www.itftennis.com/en/players/". I am in trouble with a drop down list of results where I want to click on.

Below is what I have implemented so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait, Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = 'https://www.itftennis.com/en/players/'

player='A. Parks'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until((EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//button[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]')))).click()
sbox = driver.find_element_by_id('player-search-input')
sbox.send_keys(player)
```

The previous instructions allow me to display a drop down list of different tennis players corresponding to 'A. Parks'.

Then, I do not manage to click on the player I am interested in, despite many attemps based on other posts dealing with selenium. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/PlayerApi/GetPlayerSearch?searchString=A.%20Parks

Comment: Thanks ! This helps me a lot because I can now extract the information from the json ( especially the url going to the player profile I am interested in)

Answer (score 0):

a different approach to do doing this is using requests:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.itftennis.com/tennis/api/PlayerApi/GetPlayerSearch"

querystring = {"searchString":"clara"}

payload = ""
headers = {"cookie": "visid_incap_178373=pEkKWt2XQtK4Sp5SwUlL%2B7w3l2MAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC%2F5OQZCkVsmhEafFHgeSgN; incap_ses_876_178373=vmjyTwZkw06E%2BmoBGy4oDLw3l2MAAAAAsYD2vYZqX14G6a3lefnJKw%3D%3D"}

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

this will respond with something similar to:

```
{
    "players": [
        {
            "playerId": 800714205,
            "givenName": "Alejandro",
            "familyName": "Claramonte",
            "playerNationalityCode": "ARG",
            "playerNationality": "Argentina",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/alejandro-claramonte/800714205/arg/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1490/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-male.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Alejandro Claramonte"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800504252,
            "givenName": "Ana",
            "familyName": "Clara Zaidan",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-zaidan/800504252/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Zaidan"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800677552,
            "givenName": "Ana clara",
            "familyName": "Andreazzini",
            "playerNationalityCode": "ARG",
            "playerNationality": "Argentina",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-andreazzini/800677552/arg/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana clara Andreazzini"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800503418,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara",
            "familyName": "Alcantara",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-alcantara/800503418/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Alcantara"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800713579,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara",
            "familyName": "Dominguez ",
            "playerNationalityCode": "URU",
            "playerNationality": "Uruguay",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-dominguez-/800713579/uru/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Dominguez "
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800525244,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara",
            "familyName": "Gusmini",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-gusmini/800525244/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Gusmini"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800407108,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara",
            "familyName": "Iosep",
            "playerNationalityCode": "ROU",
            "playerNationality": "Romania",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-iosep/800407108/rou/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Iosep"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800693295,
            "givenName": "Ana clara ",
            "familyName": "Fialho",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara--fialho/800693295/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Beach Tennis",
                    "value": "BT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana clara  Fialho"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800696013,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara ",
            "familyName": "Beltran Sacca",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara--beltran-sacca/800696013/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Beach Tennis",
                    "value": "BT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara  Beltran Sacca"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800673390,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara ",
            "familyName": "Pizaia Ornellas",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara--pizaia-ornellas/800673390/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara  Pizaia Ornellas"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800564881,
            "givenName": "Ana Clara Nicolau",
            "familyName": "Penteado",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-nicolau-penteado/800564881/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana Clara Nicolau Penteado"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800254485,
            "givenName": "Ana-Clara",
            "familyName": "Duarte",
            "playerNationalityCode": "BRA",
            "playerNationality": "Brazil",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/ana-clara-duarte/800254485/bra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Women's",
                    "value": "WT"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Ana-Clara Duarte"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800287469,
            "givenName": "Carlos",
            "familyName": "Clara Figueroa",
            "playerNationalityCode": "ARG",
            "playerNationality": "Argentina",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/carlos-clara-figueroa/800287469/arg/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1490/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-male.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Juniors",
                    "value": "JT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Carlos Clara Figueroa"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800615761,
            "givenName": "Clara",
            "familyName": "Albert",
            "playerNationalityCode": "FRA",
            "playerNationality": "France",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/clara-albert/800615761/fra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Beach Tennis",
                    "value": "BT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Clara Albert"
        },
        {
            "playerId": 800719678,
            "givenName": "Clara",
            "familyName": "Albert",
            "playerNationalityCode": "FRA",
            "playerNationality": "France",
            "playerProfileLink": "/en/players/clara-albert/800719678/fra/",
            "profileImage": "/media/1489/itf-uk-profile-placeholder-female.jpg?anchor=center&mode=crop&width=219&height=282&rnd=132174204480000000",
            "playedCircuits": [
                {
                    "label": "Beach Tennis",
                    "value": "BT"
                }
            ],
            "FullName": "Clara Albert"
        }
    ],
    "headToHeadLink": {
        "id": 0,
        "name": null,
        "url": "/en/head-to-head/"
    }
}
```

open you're chrome dev tools -> head to network -> click Fetch/XHR -> input a player name and see the requests that are hap

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It seems easier than what I was trying to implement.